# Test for POSIX shell compliance?

Tags: shell, posix

How can I test a shell script to verify that it is POSIX compliant?  I have a large set of scripts written for various versions of Bash and possibly other shells.  I'd like to be able to determine which are fully POSIX compliant and which are not.  Ideally, I'd like to find something like `lint` but for shell scripts.

Comment: Although it makes no claims to test for complete POSIX compliance, a commonly-used script along these lines is [`checkbashisms`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/checkbaskisms/). It tests for and reports on non-portable syntax.

Comment: Use #!/bin/ksh as a default, so you will avoid things that are easier in bash. It is only a start, you must also skip Linux improvements like `sed -i`

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3668665/is-there-a-static-analysis-tool-like-lint-or-perlcritic-for-shell-scripts

Comment: Closely related; possible duplicate. http://stackoverflow.com/q/11376975/1301972

Comment: Asked and answered: [How can I test for POSIX compliance for shell scripts?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48786/how-can-i-test-for-posix-compliance-for-shell-scripts)

Comment: See [Convert Bash Scripts To Shell](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33394706/4154375).

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to statically verify if a script is POSIX compliant because the differences are not restricted to syntax changes and some differences simply changes the way some commands behave. This [link](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-POSIX-Mode.html) describes the differences between bash and POSIX standard.

However, you can explicitly check your scripts running then with `bash --posix ./your_script.sh` or using `set -o posix` inside them.

Comment: Bash's POSIX compliant mode is unfortunately not POSIX compliant. See https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/POSIX and the end of the URL you posted. At the very least, you also need to enable the 'xpg_echo' option to get POSIX compliant "echo" behaviour. There are other things as well. I suggest using dash for posix compliant testing.