# How to test sh shell incompatible syntax/commands in bash?

Tags: bash, shell, testing, sh, compatibility

To test `sh` shell scripts in the bash environment, one may use the Bash POSIX compliant mode.

> https://hynek.me/til/which-not-posix/
>
> To run Bash in POSIX compliant mode:

```
$ bash --posix
```

> And in the shell scipt.

```
#!/bin/bash
set -o posix
```

Or if I should keep the `/#!bin/sh` hashbang?

However, for these two well known bash only features which are not supported in sh shell. they run normally and give expected output under POSIX compliant mode.

```
#!/bin/sh
set -o posix

# Associated array
declare -A array=(['me']='cat' ['you']='do   g')
echo "${array['me']}"
echo "${array['you']}"

# Double square brackets
[[ true = true ]] && echo 'yes' || echo 'no'
[[ true = false ]] && echo 'yes' || echo 'no'
```

Output:

```
gentoo_bazic /tmp/sh_test # bash --posix
bash-5.1# ./test16.sh 
cat
do   g
yes
no
bash-5.1#
```

Comment: [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) will issue warnings for any Bash-specific features used in a program with an `sh` shebang.

Comment: The website you quote is misleading if not just flatly wrong. `set -o posix` was never designed, intended, or documented to be strict enough to use for compatibility testing. It stops bash from doing things that the standard doesn't permit (with the exception of some `echo` behavior that remains prohibited unless the `xpg_echo` flag is also active), but it doesn't stop it from doing things that the standard doesn't require.

Comment: If you want a shell built to be strict enough for compatibility testing, one of those exists; use [`posh`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/posh.1.html) (in its optional POSIX mode), which was built for the purpose.

Comment: Cross-site duplicate: [How can I test for POSIX compliance of shell scripts?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48786/how-can-i-test-for-posix-compliance-of-shell-scripts), on [unix.se].

Comment: @pjh , @ Charles Duffy - Thank you. I read that post too. But I cannot install Shellcheck. The online version is good.

Comment: Nonetheless, the answer remains that _you cannot use bash, in any mode, to test a script's POSIX compliance_. It was never designed to have any features useful for that purpose.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy - _It stops bash from doing things that the standard doesn't permit._ It sounds like what I want.

Comment: @midnite, no, because there are many things the standard neither prohibits nor requires.

Comment: @midnite, the standard doesn't say a shell _is not allowed to_ have arrays; it just never says that a shell to be compliant with the standard _must_ have arrays. Thus, bash in `set -o posix` mode still has arrays, and it doesn't violate the standard by doing so.

Comment: @midnite, ...the set of things bash does the standard doesn't _allow_ it to do is fairly small, by design and intent. One of those is having `echo -e` not print the string `-e` on output, for example (`echo`'s behavior is strictly defined by the standard except when either the `-n` flag is used or backslashes are present in its arguments, so it's one of the few commands where extensions are expressly prohibited except in very limited spaces).

Comment: @midnite, similarly, the standard doesn't say that a compliant shell _must not_ support `[[` syntax extensions, so bash and ksh are still able to be POSIX-compliant shells while doing so; etc.

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-POSIX-Mode.html - This website states many different behaviours. While one is very trivial, the `POSIXLY_CORRECT` variable. `echo $POSIXLY_CORRECT` in bash gives me blank, while in the shell after issuing `bash --posix` gives me a **y**. However it is a different story in the shell script. Script behaves the same in both environments. If `#!/bin/bash` is used, `echo $POSIXLY_CORRECT` gives me blank (of course). If `#!/bin/sh` is used **or** after the `set -o posix` statement, it gives me a **y**.

Comment: However, even if in the "Bash POSIX Mode" or whenever the script have `POSIXLY_CORRECT` set to **y**, [`getopt`](https://man.archlinux.org/man/getopt.1#SCANNING_MODES) does not stop parsing as soon as the first non-option parameter is found, as it says in the manual. May be this is a problem with `getopt`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert Bash Scripts To Shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33394706/convert-bash-scripts-to-shell)

Comment: You have already established a number of cases where Bash in POSIX mode does not behave according to POSIX, and yet you keep on harping about how you wish it did. We can't help you if you don't like the answer that Bash in POSIX mode was not made for your use case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`dash`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/dash.1.html) as a first order test, since `dash` is intended as a very simple POSIX shell without any frills.

```sh
dash script.sh
```

It's available out-of-the-box on Ubuntu and some other distros, and through `apt`/`yum`/etc. on most other distros.

Comment: The manual for `dash` says it has some "Berkeley extensions" whereas `posh` is intended to eventually implement the Debian policy (and thus POSIX) and nothing more. In practice, the competition is rather even; `posh` has many odd behaviors because it was apparently forked from a shell with more features.