# Why & How fish does not support POSIX?

Tags: shell, posix, fish

I have heard about fish that it's a friendly and out-of-box shell but also it doesn't support POSIX standard. 
On the other hand I read about POSIX standard (and also I tested it on my Fedora, It's amazing and out-of-box shell now I want to change my default shell to fish).

But the matter that I opened this question for is: I misunderstood about relation between fish and POSIX standard, what do you mean about fish does NOT support POSIX exactly? & How? (Should I change my bash to fish?).

*Please explain it simple 'cause I'm a little newbie, thanks.*

Comment: The POSIX shell command language standard is given [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html). Fish's language is nothing like the one described therein; thus, it does not comply with what it means to be a "POSIX shell", which implies that one can run scripts written for that language without modification.

Comment: The biggest risks in using a non-compliant shell are that you might get in habits that result in buggy code when writing code that well be executed with a compliant shell (this is particular risk for zsh, as it looks enough like a POSIX shell that habits can translate easily and result in only subtle bugs that aren't immediately caught), and you're liable to annoy any coworkers who need to maintain your scripts. :)

Comment: Read the docs: https://fishshell.com/docs/current/design.html would be most relevant

Comment: What does "POSIX compliant" even mean? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11376975/is-there-a-minimally-posix-2-compliant-shell. It may be a blessing in disguise not even trying to be compliant.

Answer (score 45):

fish isn't and never tried to be compatible with POSIX sh.

This really just means that it's a separate language (like Java, Python or Ruby) rather than an implementation or extension of sh (like Bash, Dash and Ksh).

Obviously, just like you can't copy-paste Java snippets into a Python program, you can't copy-paste `sh` code into `fish`.

In practice, this means that when you search for things like "how do I show the current git branch in my prompt", you need to make sure you find `fish` answers because the `sh` ones won't work. Similarly, when books or instructions give commands to run, you may occasionally need to rewrite some of them manually (or open a `bash` shell and paste them there).

Whether this matters is entirely up to you, so definitely give it a go.

Comment: I am not sure "how do I show the current git branch in my prompt" is a good example. In either shell, `git branch` would suffice. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @ZhengQu People frequently add the current branch name to their shell prompt, e.g. `PS1='$(git branch --show-current) \$ '` in bash. If you want to do it in fish, you have to do it in a different way

Comment: Extending the shell is a very different thing from running commands though. "commands to run" implies running commands would be a lot more different than it actually is. Running a command is basically always the same. Adding logic to construct the command and combine commands is not. Using only git commands is not a problem and works just the same in fish.

Answer (score 25):

Actually, `fish`  is *not* compliant with the POSIX `sh` [definition](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html). But neither is `csh` (and probably `zsh`). You still can use `fish` as your interactive shell.

For example `echo $$` shows the pid of the shell in POSIX `sh`. But with `fish` it does not.

<sup>(and that is why I did not switch to `fish` and keep using `zsh` as my daily interactive login shell)</sup>

You could change your interactive login shell (using `chsh`) to `fish`.

But if you write [shell scripts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_script), writing them for the POSIX `sh` specification make these scripts more portable. (You'll use the [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) `#!/bin/sh` to start them, it is understood by Linux [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html)). In some cases, you don't care about [portability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_portability) of your shell script and you could make them start with `#!/usr/bin/fish`  to be `fish` scripts. Then they won't work on systems without `fish`.

Also, the [system(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html) C standard library function uses `/bin/sh -c`.

I enjoyed very much [Yann Regis-Gianas' talk](https://youtu.be/fiJR4_059HA) on *POSIX [s]hell* at FOSDEM2018.

Comment: zsh is definitely not compliant with its default runtime configuration (the definition is explicit on word-splitting for unquoted expansion, f/e) -- but it does a better job than bash does when started under the name `sh`.

Comment: I use fish mainly but if I have to copy and paste something, I just switch to zsh.

Comment: You can use [bass](https://github.com/edc/bass), a fish plugin that ease the use of bash like commands directly from fish.